# Vim: Почти полная замена всех клавиш для команд

Tags: vim, vi

Здравствуйте, я с вимом немного знаком, умею из него выходить, но всеми возможностями пока не пользуюсь. И у меня назрел такой вопрос:

А нормально ли заменить почти все комбинации клавиш, хоткеи и тд?
Не скажется ли это на чем-то в дальнейшем и могут ли появится на этом пути какие-то проблемы, как техничные, так и другие (привычка, невозможность пользоваться "нормальным" вимом)?
И пробовал ли кто-то идти таким путем?

Вот у меня ноутбук, на клавиатуре стрелки и всякие Home/End находятся близко, так что нужды в hjkl и подобном нет. 
Далее, w и b находятся далеко, и мне кажется, что удобнее было бы, что б клавиши скачек по словам находились рядом (типа q и w). Ctrl + fbduye что бы листать текст тоже как-то можно оптимизировать. И все в таком духе.

Что скажете, насколько это труЪ и если ли смысл в тексте выше, или конфигурировать такие базовые вещи не стоит?

Comment: IMHO не стоит, поскольку vi есть *на всех \*nix* (и похоже это единственная причина для его использования).

Comment: @avp ну nano тоже. Так же люди этот конфиг хранят в облаке и качают туда, где нужен вим. Так что это не единственная (и не главная) причина.

Comment: философия юникса как раз не запрещает это сделать. А GNU и компания вообще говорят - переписывайте код так, что бы удобно было (только копирайты не забывайте правильно проставлять),

Если такой модифицированный вим будет помогать Вам зарабатывать в сотни раз больше денег - делаейте. Если же Вы только думаете, что это теоретически может помочь - бросайте.

Comment: я как-то раз думал взять игровые педали и на них повесить всякие Ctrl да Alt, уж очень часто хоткеи использую.

Comment: Ну, nano это вообще не редактор, а так, мелкий прибамбас. Для себя я везде (в т.ч. в винде) использую emacs, а "на выезде" vi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я как-то пытался так сделать (долго работал с `SlickEdit`). Бонусов особых не получил. Вернулся к стандартной конфигурации.

Магия вима в неких магических сочетаниях клавиш, именно на которые заточены маны и туториалы.

К примеру - `v i t =` - форматирует блок внутри тега. И таких комбинаций много. Переопределив комбинации клавиш сложно будет такие вещи 1 - воспроизводить; 2 - запомнить.

Answer (score 1):

Что касается конфигурации: представьте, что вам нужно решить какую-то задачу удаленно на чужой машине с помощью Vim (конфиги какие-нибудь отредактировать, например). Вам придется залить свою конфигурацию, потом работать, потом вернуть конфигурацию «как было».

- Во-первых, вы потратите дополнительное время.
- Во-вторых, не факт, что вам дадут доступ. И тогда вам придется работать на абсолютно непривычной раскладке.
- В-третьих, вы можете сломать конфигурацию, которая была. Например, окажется, что там тоже какая-то нестандартная, а бэкап сделать забыли.

Так что на такое стоит идти только в случае, [если это сразу приносит вам значительное повышение производительности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446108/vim-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4/446129#comment472601_446108) или какое-то другое существенное преимущество.

Вообще, вопрос достаточно неопределенный и зависит от того, с чем вы работаете. Если это современные высокоуровневые языки, то, на мой взгляд, наилучшая производительность будет с полнофункциональной IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите EMACS, с ним именно так и поступают обычно, полно примеров. Vim действительно хорош такой, как он есть.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю что стэк из:

1. [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe)
2. [SnipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540)
3. [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)
4. [Vim](http://www.vim.org/)

и еще нескольких языкозависимых плагинов по вкусу
на данный момент лучше, понятнее, проще, быстрее, дешевле и эффективнее, чем **любая** профессиональная коммерческая IDE существующая на рынке.

А редактировать что-то на  другой удаленной системе через встроенный vi по SSH это вообще бредовая идея. Просто используйте для этой цели частный репозиторий какой-нибудь VCS.

- Редактируйте нужный файл в локальном репозитории со своей удобной
  конфигурацией Vim.
- Коммитите в глобальный.
- С удаленной машины просто обновляете одной командой. Все.

По поводу переопределения клавиш, то я использую такую схему:

<kbd>hjkl</kbd> -> <kbd>jkl;</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl + hjkl</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl +jkl;</kbd>

<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> -> <kbd>Esc</kbd>

<kbd>Tab</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl+k</kbd>.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> ->  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Очень удобно, т.к. читерски позволяет вообще не нажимать оригинальные кнопки <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> и <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, которые расположены слишком далеко на китайских клавиатурах, установленных на большинстве домашних компьютеров.

Comment: А еще одно, что думаете про всякие vim-плагины для IDE (в первую очередь Intellij)?

Comment: @Mentat Не пользовался, но там [версия этого плагина 0.46](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16) и ему 5 лет всего. А Vim больше 20 лет допиливают уже. Эмуляция бесплатного текстового редактора в пропиетарной IDE, судя по всему костыль, т.к. оно наверняка не сможет предоставить все нужные плагины к нему. Я еще пользуюсь firefox + vimperator, хорошая связка, с ней можно сайтики вроде этого удобно скроллить без мышки вообще.

Comment: А сверху еще вместо KDE [тайловый оконный менеджер i3](https://i3wm.org/) накидываешь под FreeBSD и в результате получается каноничный труЪ сисадминский терминал ровно за ноль рублей. Свобода она такая.